Flutter app build fails: "Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file"
When I run the flutter run command line, it shows this error message:
`Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 120814 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: null
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.70.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:75)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.b(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:136)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 120814 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.JT.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:14)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.JT.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:22)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.n30.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:524)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.i30.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:371)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:455)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:756)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:24)
    ... 41 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
           Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
[!] App requires Multidex support
    Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

    Your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` does not contain `android:name="${applicationName}"` under the `application` element. This may be due to creating your project with an old version of Flutter. Add the `android:name="${applicationName}"` attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml to enable Flutter's multidex support:

        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          ...
          <application
            ...
            android:name="${applicationName}"
            ...>

    You may also roll your own multidex support by following the guide at: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
`


I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, reinstalling the app on the device.
I'm using Flutter version [3.19.6] on [Windows].
I have modify the build.gradle

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}


But It's stuck at √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk., then nothing happens
I cloned the same project as my friend, but theirs runs without issues while mine crashes. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?
How can I resolve this "Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file" error and successfully build my Flutter app? Thank you.

Try setting minSdkVersion to 21. That way setting multidex is not needed
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_application_2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

Otherwise, double check if your android -> app -> build.gradle is like this:
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_application_2"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

